# Change UITabBar selectedItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, swift2

How can I programmatically change the selected item in a UITabBar?

Comment: For me this answer perfectly worked!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326494/5746625

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Swift 3 and later

As of Swift 3, you can also use

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // (or any other existing index)
```

(Thank you, [@nidomiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469540).)

---

### Swift 2.2 and earlier

Try the following

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![newIndex] as! UITabBarItem
```

Assuming you have access to the `UITabBarController` that owns the `UITabBar`, you can do the following

```
self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers![newIndex] as! UIViewController
```

The above line of code should be put somewhere inside of the `UITabBarController` subclass.

But if you have access to the tab bar controller from "outside," do the following

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![newIndex] as! UIViewController
```

Comment: I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: Is the `UITabBar` owned by a `UITabBarController`? And, if so, can you obtain a reference to it?

Comment: Yes. Setting the property on the reference gives the same error.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Can you please modify your answer to: selectedViewController = viewControllers![newIndex] as UIViewController

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help. I modified my answer. I updated it to use the forced downcast operator `as!`, which is Swift 2 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5 and Later

```
class YOUR_TABBAR_CONTROLLER: UITabBarController {    

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.selectedIndex = 0 (or any other existing index)

  }
}
```