# How do I navigate to view using tabbarcontroller through popover's unwind segue

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar, selectedindex

All of my view controllers are linked using a tab bar controller, and it works great. My only issue is when a popover is displayed I am unable to send the user to another view controller for the appropriate circumstance. I tried using

tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1

Here is some pertinent code:

```
//user selects a row this function triggers an event
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.tableviewlineneeds
    {
        forklift.paramneeds = "\(forklift.k)&f=\(forklift.forkliftid)&id=\(forklift.needuniqueid[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])&o="
        let popneeds = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "verifyneedsaction") as! NeedsActionPopover
        popneeds.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popneeds.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        popneeds.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popneeds.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableviewlineneeds
        popneeds.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = tableviewlineneeds.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        popneeds.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 225, height: 180)
        popneeds.needitem = forklift.itemneeds[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        self.present(popneeds, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if tableView == self.tableviewlinepickup
    {
        forklift.parampickup = "\(forklift.k)&f=\(forklift.forkliftid)&id=\(forklift.pickupuniqueid[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])&o="
        let poppickup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "verifypickupaction") as! PickupActionPopover
        poppickup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        poppickup.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        poppickup.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        poppickup.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableviewlinepickup
        poppickup.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = tableviewlinepickup.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        poppickup.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 180)
        forklift.pickuplocation = forklift.locationpickup[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        poppickup.pickupitem = forklift.itempickup[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        self.present(poppickup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

That is where the popup for the pickup is triggered. and here is the unwind segue:

```
 @IBAction func unwindLinePickup(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    if segue.identifier == "confirm"
    {
        switch forklift.pickuplocation
        {
        case "Line 2":
            self.sendToMoveView()
        case "Line 3":
            self.sendToMoveView()
        case "Line 7":
            self.sendToMoveView()
        case "Line 8":
            self.sendToMoveView()
        default:
            API.HTTPCall(forklift.parampickup, url: forklift.postmove!, method: "POST", int: 10)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my function to send to the scanner view controller:

```
func sendToMoveView()
{
    guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

I have tried using the tabBarController.selectedIndex in places like my viewDidAppear override and it works for setting a default or the layout subviews, and I have set a default view before using it in the AppDelegate. So what must I do to use it in this situation, because navigating to the VC any other way gives me a VC with no tab bar :( I'd greatly appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue to my answer in this question: [Change UITabbar selectedItem in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329680/change-uitabbar-selecteditem-in-swift-2-0][1])

I then removed my unwind segue from the initial view controller and embedded it into the tab bar controller and changed my sendToMoveView function to look like the following:

```
func sendToMoveView()
{
    self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers?[1]
}
```

I also redid my unwind connection in the storyboard just to be safe even though it was showing the correct controller. Just want to point out that the change I made will not work if you have not given a proper storyboard id to the tabbar controller. This one gave me a head ache.