# Go to custom tab in UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with the first screen being a login screen. Once the user has logged in, it segues to my tab bar controller with 5 tabs but at the moment it always opens the first tab by default.

How do I get it to open the 3-rd tab? I've done it before in AppDelegate but that was for an app with the starting screen being the tab bar view, but it doesn't seem to work when it's not.

Swift 3, iOS 10.3, Xcode 8.3 Beta 2

Comment: Where are you putting you code and what is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically switching between tabs within Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325923/programatically-switching-between-tabs-within-swift)

Comment: @SeyyedParsaNeshaei nope

Comment: @KyloR Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UITabBarController`'s `viewWillAppear` do

```
selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe I tried so many things and it was literally this simple. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it's right in front of you and you just can't see it...happens to all of us! Glad I could help :)