# How do I open a view controller from the app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, rootview, uiscenedelegate

I want to open the "Menu View Controller", when a local notification is opened from the Notification Center. My problem is that I do not know how I can open a view controller from the AppDelegate. All solutions I found did not work, because it were for older Xcode versions before  the SceneDelegate was introduced. This is the function in the AppDelegate where I want to call the view controller.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // missing code to open menu view controller

        completionHandler()

    }
```

I use a tab bar controller to navigate between some view controllers. I am not sure if that makes a difference.
Here is how the important part of my storyboard looks.
[image: roo]

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Look up the accepted answer on the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325923/programmatically-switching-between-tabs-within-swift

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately does that not work for me. I only get the error value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member of 'window'. Only the last response is for iOS13. In that case I have to implement the solution in SceneDelegate, but I still do not know how to get it to the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible ways of doing this:

**1. Instantiate your tab bar controller via storyboard.**

Go to your storyboard and set a storyboard ID for your tab bar controller inside the identity inspector.

Once you go that, you can instantiate your view controller like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
if let tabController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabControllerID") as? UITabController {
    tabController.selectedIndex = index
}
```

2. Or, you can access scene delegate from your AppDelegate and use window -> rootViewController to get access to your tabController:

```
    let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
    if let sceneDelegate = scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {  
        if let tabController = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
              tabController.selectedIndex = index
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second version worked for me. I just had to change the UITabController to UITabBarController.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, the second one also worked for me.